# Python analogue of Matlab's interval numbers like 1:2:5

Tags: python

Does anybody know whether Python can do the same thing as `for i= 1:2:5` in Matlab? So `i`=1,3,5.

I know I can use other approaches to do this, but I want to know the equivalent form in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
for i in xrange(1,6,2):
    print i
```

This print:

```
1
3
5
```

> Use xrange instead of range if you are using python 2.x because it is more efficient as it generates an iterable object, and not the whole list.

Comment: Your last point is only true in Python 2.  In Python 3, only `range` exists, and it's the same as Python 3's `xrange`.

Comment: @jwodder thanks dude i edit my answer based on your note

Comment: @HasanRamezani You're welcome dada ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function:

```
for i in range(1, 6, 2):
    print(i)
```